# How do I interpret results from scipy pdf() function in concerns with the probability density function

Tags: python

I am working on a personal project and want to understand what the output of Scipy's pdf() function. I understand that the PDF is for one singular line under a distribution curve so finding a point under that function would be zero. But when working with scipy, i get a number im not quite understanding.

```
from scipy.stats import norm

norm.pdf(0)
#0.3989422804014327

norm.pdf(0, loc=5, scale=10)
#0.03520653267642995

r = np.random.randn(10)

norm.pdf(r)
#array([0.39739838, 0.31770265, 0.06576943, 0.252755  , 0.38386191,
       #0.31203894, 0.34385005, 0.39185893, 0.39848757, 0.38723303])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting it simply, `pdf()` returns the `y` value upon the distribution curve (gaussian if you use a normal distribution) given the `x` and other parameters you supply. Probability for a given interval is defined as the respective area under curve.